# Until now, what is the fastest optimization algorithm of non-smooth convex functions

Tags: convex-optimization

I am wondering if I minimize a non-smooth convex function, which solver should I choose. I think I should choose a fastest one with a big convergence rate. Subgradient descent is always on the textbook. But it is slow. I am seeking a state of the art optimization algorithm for non-smooth case.

I actually study a general case. E.g., the regression problem $$\|Kx-y\|+|x|$$, where $$x\in\mathbb{R}^d,K\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$$. I mean I not only try to solve the regression problem, but also others. So I cannot make it too specific. Got a good studff,http://napsu.karmitsa.fi/nsosoftware/. There are several algorithms for nonsmooth case. Which should I use?

Comment: It depends on a number of things. First of all if your problem is linear or nonlinear. I am not sure what the best algorithm is out there, but if you want to do some research a great person to look at is [Carsten Gräser](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/graeser/). He has done convex minimisation problems in the linear and nonlinear case. His PhD thesis would probably have some excellent references

Comment: There is no one right answer here; it depends considerably on the specific function. Perhaps if you offered more details about the functions you are considering, we can offer more specific advice.

Comment: @KeeranBrabazon, Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant, Thanks. I consider a general case here. Happy weekend.

Comment: This can be expressed as a linear program for which there are many good solvers from simplex to interior point...

Comment: Yep. And that's why it's good to get as specific as possible. This is a relatively trivial problem to solve. (I assume you meant $\|\cdot\|$ instead of $|\cdot|$ above?)

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant, yup, I correct it.